# Angular factory definition breaking with requires

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jasmine, factory

I have an Angularjs factory defined like:

```
angular.module('myapp').factory('myService', myService);
function myService($http) {
```

However this is not being found by my jasmine tests. If however I add an empty requires array it works in the tests but the application itself breaks.

```
angular.module('myapp', []).factory('myService', myService);
function myService($http) {
```

Looking at https://code.angularjs.org/1.5.8/docs/api/ng/function/angular.module for the requires attribute it says

> If specified then new module is being created. If unspecified then the module is being retrieved for further configuration.

But I don't understand how that would break things, and how I can get both the tests and application working.

The service is included in the test file with:

```
describe('myService', function() {
  var myService;
  beforeEach(module('myapp'));
  beforeEach(inject(function($injector) {
    myService = $injector.get('myService');
  }));
  ...
```

Comment: why you're doing `angular.module('myapp', [])` again if `myapp` already initialized..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that where my module dependencies were defined it has

```
angular.module('tcom.search', ['ngSanitize', 'ui.bootstrap'])
```

So I had to update my grunt config to include the bower components

```
    karma: {
      unit: {
        options: {
          frameworks: ['jasmine'],
          singleRun: true,
          browsers: ['PhantomJS'],
          files: [
            'bower_components/angular/angular.js',
            'bower_components/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js',
            'bower_components/angular-sanitize/angular-sanitize.js',
            'bower_components/angular-bootstrap/ui-bootstrap.js',
```